# Help with implemented Piecewise in Module

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

Suppose we have an ODE in the form:

```
 f''[r] + f'[r] == t f[r]+h[r]
```

where

```
h[r_]: Piecewise[{{t, 0 <= r <= a}, {0, a < r <= 1}}]
```

I am using `Module` function and I do not know how to implement `Piecewise` with `Module[{x,y,…},expr]`. Here is my tried
        `gcd[t0_] := Module[{t = t0},{f''[r] +  f'[r]) == t f[r] + h[r]].` However, Mathematica does not know what is `h[r]`since `h[r]` defines outside the `Module`. Help?

Comment: Parameter `ϵ` isn't defined!

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are trying to do, since your question has incomplete information. You did not even show how you want to call the function.

But it is best to pass all information between functions via arguments and not use global context to read.  This makes your code more robust.

```
ClearAll[ode, h, f, r];
ode[t_, a_] := f''[r] + f'[r] == t f[r] + h[t, a];
h[t_, a_] := Piecewise[{{t, 0 <= r <= a}, {0, a < r <= 1}}];
```

Now define the function

```
gcd[t_, ode_, f_, r_] := Module[{a = 0.5},
  DSolve[ode[t, a], f[r], r]
  ]
```

Now call it

```
t = 0.4;
gcd[t, ode, f, r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are other ways to do this. It will help if you showed actual example of call also.

**Answer comment**

You have few errors in your code posted. Try this

```
ClearAll[f, r];
h[t_, a_, r_] := Piecewise[{{t, 0 <= r <= a}, {0, a < r <= 1}}] 
gcd[t_, f_, r_] := Module[{a = 0.5},
   DSolve[f''[r] + f'[r] == t f[r] + h[t, a, r], f[r], r]
   ];
Table[gcd[t, f, r], {t, {4.2, 4.5, 0.1}}]
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nassaer here What I did: First I defined :  `h[t_, a_,r_] := Piecewise[{{t, 0 <= r <= a}, {0, a < r <= 1}}]` and then `gcd[t_,h_,r_] := Module[{a = 0.5,t=t0},
  DSolve[f''[r] + f'[r] == t f[r] + h[t, a,r], f[r], r]` ];  Now call it `Table[gcd[t_,f_,r_] , {t, 4.2, 4.5, 0.1}]`

Comment: @user69676 one obvious problem, is that you are passing `t` as argument to `gcd` and also defining local `t` inside the same module. You can't do this. You have other problems. Will post corrected version

Comment: .@Nasser Thanks! Do you how to use `WhenEvent[0 <= r <= a, t], WhenEvent[ a < r <= 1,]` instead of `Piecewise`?

Comment: @user69676 `WhenEvent` is not really meant to be used in place of `Piecewise`. WhenEvent is for use in something completely different. With NDSolve and such. So you can just stick to `Piecewise` for defining functions.